# Run Command Line Script from Finder's contextual menu

Tags: automator, applescript

I have a shell script that deletes exif data from images.

I would like to right-click the folder with the images and execute the command from the context menu.
 How can I do this?

The Shell script is:

```
exiftool -all= -overwrite_original test
```

where test is the dir with the images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Snow Leopard, you can create a Service, and it'll show up in a submenu of the contextual menu (as well as in the Services submenu of the Finder menu).  To do this:

1. Run /Applications/Automator.app
2. Choose the Service template
3. Set the Service Receives Selected pop-up (above the workflow column on the right) to "Files and Folders"
4. Find the Run Shell Script action in the second column (the search field at the top can help), and drag it to the workflow column
5. Set the action's Pass input: pop-up to "as arguments"
6. In the template script that appears, replace `echo "$f"` with `exiftool -all= -overwrite_original "$f"` -- the script should now look like this:

   ```
   for f in "$@"
   do
       exiftool -all= -overwrite_original "$f"
   done
   ```
7. Save the Service with some descriptive name

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I just wanted to add that in step #3, "Files and Folders" in "Finder.app" I also skipped the loop with [exiftool -all= -overwrite_original "$@"]

Comment: For some reason, it didn't occur to me that `exiftool` might be able to take multiple files & folders.  As for step 3, restricting the service to Finder.app doesn't really matter -- what other app do you select files & folders in?  BTW, one limitation of this is that the Run Shell Script action doesn't do a very good job of error reporting, so if anything can go wrong, the script should take care of its own reporting.