# Using AppleScript to convert MP3 to WAV via Finder?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, high-sierra

How would I use Automator/AppleScript to convert a selected bunch of MP3s to WAVs (from folder1 to folder1 - so retaining original folder), please?

I'm running High Sierra and would prefer not to attack the commandline just to get a mp3 back to wav.

Comment: You do realise you already lost quality & that re-converting to WAV will not restore any of that?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22803/converting-wav-to-mp3-using-lame-and-automator?rq=1

Comment: tbh, I'd just use [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) or [Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/) Both have their adherents, both are 'as good' as each other, depending on your use case.

Comment: Automator does not have a built-in Convert to MP3 to WAV action, so some form of scripting will need to be used that would probably have to include using a third-party utility from the command line, albeit scripted. Additionally, Tetsujin's first comment about the quality is notable as well as his second comment. I'd use XLD (because I have it installed) and forget about Automator/AppleScript, as XLD will do batch processing. That said, if you have the original Audio CD source, if that's where it originally came from, I'd use it instead of the MP3 files.

Comment: if you happen to still have Quicktime 7 pro, it can read mp3 and write wav, and it's scriptable (and it works in Sierra). But to use it with Automator, you will have to get the list of file in Automator and then to pass them to a "Run Applescript" step that actually commands Quicktime.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am fully cognizant of this fact (MP3->Wav file fidelity loss). However, I need to make sure that a podcast episode uses the very same wavefile I provided, and for that I need to have the original wavefile and the MP3->WAV wavefile, just so I can see that it's the newest version and not some older version. 
Also, I would prefer to do it in-Finder with a Service, rather than boot up some 3rd party app.

Comment: @GioValerio I'll see if I still have a bought Quicktime 7 Pro left, thanks for the advice!